# Discord.py Reddit Meme Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a command that posts a random meme from reddit, but i keep getting a 401 HTTP Response error, here is my code:

```
@commands.command()
async def meme(self, ctx):
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='id here',
  client_secret='secret here',
  user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/7.5b3349 Mobile/14F89 Safari/603.2.4')

memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()

post = random.randint(1, 10)

for i in range(0, post):
    submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

await self.client.say(submission.url)
```

Comment: A 401 error usually means you are not authorized. Such as you didn't log in or you have incorrect cliend_id/client_secret. Are you sure that your client_id and client_secret are correct?

Comment: Yeah solved it a while ago, turns out I had to create a reddit app and get its agent and not just put in a random browser agent haha

Comment: @avslav , you can post that as an answer and accept it.